# avro events from kafka to HDFS as ORC files with flume

Tags: flume, avro

I have kafka cluster that receives avro events from producers.

I would like to use flume in order to consume these events and put them as ORC files in HDFS

Is this possible with flume?

Does anyone have example of a configuration file demonstrating how to do it?